# How to create a container inside pod explicitly?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

In a kubernetes cluster"s pod there are 2 container in running state and the pod is configured auto-scale. Now I want to create a another container inside the same pod with the same image that both running container have explicitly while don’t stopping the running container.

How can I acheive this?

Cluster information:
Kubernetes version: 1.14, 
Cloud being used: (put bare-metal if not on a public cloud) : Google Cloud
and Host OS: Debian

Update the deployment-yaml file, include the 3rd container image and then rolling-update.

Comment: This sounds like you want to have only one copy of the container in the deployment's pod spec, and just use something like `kubectl scale` to increase the replica count and launch a new pod.  Do you have a specific reason they must be in the same pod?

Comment: You definitely want to scale the deployment. If you try to run 2 copies of the same container in your pod, you will run into issues since both containers will share resources. You'll have issues like port conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Scaling in Kubernetes operates pods, not containers within a pod. You create a [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) and set the desired number of replicas. This will ensure a corresponding number of pods for you.